# MongoDB sort works only on a section of the collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a PHP-MongoDB project. I'm using:

- CodeIgniter
- PHP MongoDB Driver
- Xampp
- The [MongoDB Connector from
  vvvlad](http://www.vvvlad.com/resources/mongodb)

I have a problem with the sorting method.

I have this collection (notice the ['order'] property):

```
[4d642296bb3dfde40c000002] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000002
            )

        [project_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [parent_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [version] => 0
        [title] => IntroducciÃ³n
        [body] => IntroducciÃ³n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [order] => 0
    )

[4d642296bb3dfde40c000003] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000003
            )

        [project_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [parent_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [version] => 0
        [title] => Marco Contextual
        [body] => Marco Contextual Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [order] => 2
    )

[4d642296bb3dfde40c000004] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000004
            )

        [project_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [parent_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [version] => 0
        [title] => Marco Conceptual
        [body] => Marco Conceptual Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [order] => 3
    )

[4d642296bb3dfde40c000005] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000005
            )

        [project_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [parent_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [version] => 0
        [title] => Capitulo I
        [body] => Capitulo I Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [order] => 4
    )

[4d642296bb3dfde40c000006] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000006
            )

        [project_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [parent_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [version] => 1
        [title] => Capitulo II
        [body] => Capitulo II Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [order] => 5
    )

[4d642296bb3dfde40c000007] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000007
            )

        [project_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [parent_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [version] => 0
        [title] => ConclusiÃ³n
        [body] => ConclusiÃ³n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        [order] => 6
    )

[4d6422a7bb3dfde40c000008] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
                [$id] => 4d6422a7bb3dfde40c000008
            )

        [project_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [parent_id] => 4d642296bb3dfde40c000001
        [version] => 0
        [title] => i1
        [body] => New Lorem Ipsum
        [order] => 1
    )
```

That I get from this:

```
function get_entries(){

    $project_id = key($this->projects_model->get_project());

    $data=array(
        'project_id' => $project_id
    );

    return $this->mdb->get(
        $this->mdb->sinapsisDB->entries,
        $data,
        array('order'=>1)
    );
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to sort the results using the ['order'] attribute, but the returned array is not sorted that way, is noteworthy that the first 6 indexes are created on a loop all at the same time, and the last one (that is not in order) is created later by a function that searches the desired order for the new entry and make the necessary ['order'] operations to make them fit in place.

At first I thought that the 'get' method from the vvvlad connector was not working but the same happens when I try

```
db.entries.find().sort({$order:1})
```

in the Mongo Client

I think this has some relation with 'indexed values' but I don't undestand why this simple sorting method does not work.

Thanks in advance for you time :)

Comment: You are running "db.entries.find().sort({$order:1})" via the shell? Shouldn't it be db.entries.find().sort({'order':1}) ?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following test on Mongo and everything looks correct:

```
db.foo.drop()
db.foo.insert( { text : "blah", order : 1 } )
db.foo.insert( { text : "bl", order : 0 } )
db.foo.insert( { text : "blahblah", order : 2 } )
printjson(db.foo.find().sort( { order : 1 } ).toArray())
```

I am not familiar with vvvlad's code but there is definitely a problem with your shell example.

```
db.entries.find().sort({$order:1})
```

The `$order` is incorrect (no `$`).

Are you sure that vvvlad's code supports sorting?

Comment: Thank you very much I tested your suggestion on my side also I was reading further on MongoDB documentation and PHP.

I was using print_r to show collection on the screen, but I was saving the last ['order'] attribute as a string instead of an Integer, that was the error that prevent the correct sorting. Stupid error but happens when learning many things at once hehe

Thankyou very much for the answer & your time :)... Oh and yes vvvlad supports sorting :) my bad all the time.